# Dipped headlight near side won't turn on

Tags: headlight, opel, corsa

I have a 2004 Opel corsa (right hand drive). The dipped/low beam headlight in the driver side has stopped working. My immediate guess was the bulb so I replaced it and it didn't work. The old bulb looked OK so I tried putting that bulb in th left side and it works. This rules out an issue with the bulb.

I then checked the fuse box. I wasn't sure what perspective left and right was from so I replaced all the fuses for the headlights low and high beam. Based on [this post](http://www.corsa-c.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?177724-*NEW!*-Absolutely-EVERYTHING-You-Need-to-Know-on-ICE-Please-Read-Before-Posting-!!&p=3375020#/topics/177724?page=1&_k=1pbjn2)  I replaced 36, 37, 43, and 44. This covers any possible fault with a fuse. None of the fuses were blown, but they do have some blue/gray corrosion on them and they are a bit black. After replacing all the fuses the same headlight is still not working.

High beams and all other lights on both sides are working fine so I'm not sure it could be wiring either. Are there other secret fuses or things I can check to see what is causing this?

The radio was broken in the car for quite some time. Turns out the fuse behind the radio itself was blown. I replaced it today and it's fixed now, but could this being blown long term have any relationship?

Comment: Perhaps it's a relay?